# Convert text in RichTextBox to Speech sound

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, audio, text-to-speech

I have a problem. I have a `RichTextBox`, and I want convert text to speech audio, so is  there some library or program to do this ? I want do this in C#, WinForms.

Update:

```
private void aiutoVocaleToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string contenuto_valore = TextBox_stampa_contenuto.Text.Trim();
    var s = new System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer();
    s.Speak(contenuto_valore);
}
```

the program says that there are not reference to assembly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the MS TTS:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Use TTS:

```
private static SpeechSynthesizer speaker;

public static void Main(String[] args){
  speaker = new SpeechSynthesizer();
  speaker.SetOutputToDefaultAudioDevice();
  speaker.Rate = 1;
  speaker.Volume = 100;
  speaker.SelectVoiceByHints(VoiceGender.Female, VoiceAge.Adult);
  speaker.SpeakAsync("Hello World"); 
}

private static List<VoiceInfo> GetInstalledVoices() {
  var listOfVoiceInfo = from voice
                        in  speaker.GetInstalledVoices()
                        select voice.VoiceInfo;

  return listOfVoiceInfo.ToList<VoiceInfo>();
}
```

Just read the `RichTextBox's` [`Text`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.text%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to get the Text

Answer (score 0):

Read the `RichTextBox` value (split it if it's very large text) and make a *request* to translate.google.com as:

> http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=Your%20Text%20Here

You can obtain the *sound* file generated using `HTTP GET`, if you must. Remeber, your client will need to have access to internet

---

You'll need to reference `System.Speech.dll` in order to use `SpeechSynthesizer()`. Follow there steps:

1. Locate and right click *References* in *Solution Explorer*
2. Click *Add* option from the context menu
3. Reference Manager pop-up will show, In Assemblies - Framework try to locate `System.Speech.dll`
4. If you can find, check it and click <kbd>OK</kbd>

Now you can run the following code;

```
private void aiutoVocaleToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer())
    {        
        synth.SetOutputToDefaultAudioDevice();

        synth.Speak(TextBox_stampa_contenuto.Text.Trim());
    }
}
```

Comment: @RedFerrari96 instead of sharing your code via comments, you can edit your question and include the code. And you'll need to add `System.Speech.dll` to your project references.

Comment: Sorry, but i forget that i can put code in my question.

Comment: @RedFerrari96 You can, i did it for you hope you will provide your work next time you ask ;)

Comment: So  must I introduce new library called 'System.Speech.dll'?
Thanks.

Comment: @RedFerrari96 you are welcome. You can *upvote* the answers you find helpful, and *accept* only one answer that you think is the best answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Built-in to .NET

```
var s = new System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer();
s.Speak("hello");
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms586901(v=vs.110).aspx